# Nested collection fetched in runtime but not in test

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, h2, junit5

I have a class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "car")
public class CarEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")
    private List<WheelEntity> wheels;

    private String number;
}
```

And a query finding an entity by one of its parameters and fetching nested collection:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM car c WHERE c.number=:loanContract")
Optional<CarEntity> findByNumber(@Param("number") String number);
```

Everything works fine in runtime, but when I try to test it, the nested collection in the entity read from database is always `null`. I'm using Junit5 and H2 in-memory database.

Comment: Is it the same database during runtime and test?

Comment: Yes, it's the same

Comment: provide the code where you fetch the data in code and in test